# How to tell CSS my Web Component attribute has mutated

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

If you look at me simple example [here](https://richardmaher.github.io/MenuButton/test_button.html) you with see that test_button.html has some inline CSS: -

```
#myBtn[clicked="true"] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This seems to work as long as I go through the componet's attribute setter for "clicked". That is the AttributeChanged event is called and CSS reacts.

But as my clicked event occurs on the Shadow DOM there is no way I can see (bar using a closure to send the custom element's "this" to the event handler) of accessing the accessor for "clicked".

The user/caller of my Web Component *could* stick a data-clicked attribute on #myBtn and maintain it themselves in their own event handler but shouldn't attribute-change be something that can bubble up from the shadow DOM to the light DOM?

Comment: I want to see full code, not result

Comment: Right-Button -> View Source ? or https://github.com/RichardMaher/MenuButton

Comment: You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, shoolboy error :-( Just realized if I stick the event listener on "this" rather than "this.#button" then the event Handler can simply this.target.clicked="true" and CSS is informed.

But will I still have access to the Shadow DOM from abc-menu-button?

I've update [the code](https://github.com/RichardMaher/MenuButton). Basically I added an event to the loght DOM element: -

```
this.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.target.clicked = e.target.clicked == "true" ? "false" : "true";
    });
```

Now the caller CSS is happy.

FYI I found this very informative [link](https://pm.dartus.fr/blog/a-complete-guide-on-shadow-dom-and-event-propagation/) in my searches regarding Shadow DOM event propagation..